# Sequence convergence with parameter

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, induction, exponential-function

I need to find the parameter $a$ so that the following series converges: $ x_0=a$, $x_{n+1}=x_n^2-4x_n+6$.What is the condition for this series to converge and why?

Comment: Do you mean sequence instead of series?

Comment: Yes, sequence,I'm sorry I didn't know how to translate it

Comment: What methods have you tried. People will down vote your post if you do not include your attempts

Comment: hint: for the sequence to converge it must achieve a value of $x_n$ for which  $x_{n+1}=x_n$

Comment: @WW1 Errr... no, why?

Comment: A sequence converging to a point is equivalent to the terms getting close together i.e. Cauchy Sequences are Convergent Sequences @ClementC.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson So, according to you the sequence $a_n = 1-1/n$ "achieves a value of $a_n$ for which $a_{n+1}=a_n$"? (since it converges to $1$) That's unfortunately untrue. The terms *converge* to the limit, never *achieve* its value. I know what a Cauchy sequence is. I object to the idea that a sequence converges if its terms "achieve" the value of the limit, as written by WW1.

Comment: (also, if you want to be picky, Cauchy sequences are convergent sequence *in complete spaces.* But that mention of Cauchy sequences has nothing to do with WW1's comment, nor with mine.)

Comment: @ClementC. I should have said $\lim_{n\to \infty}(x_{n+1}-x_n)=0$ - I was trying to make it easier for the OP to find the answers

Comment: @WW1 Well, that is not a sufficient condition for convergence (it does not imply Cauchy-ness). Take $a_n = \sqrt{n}$ as a counterexample.

Comment: That's not what i am saying. Suppose $\{a_n\}$ converges to a limit $L$ in other words for large $N$ $|a_n-L| <\epsilon/2$ for sufficiently large $N$. Chose $m \geq N$. Then, $|a_n-a_m| \leq |a_n-L| + |a_m-L| <\epsilon$ i.e $a_n$ is differs from $a_m$ by at most $\epsilon$. In the limit they are equal.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson What **is** your point? WW1 used some specific choice of words, which happens to be factually wrong and misleading. You are arguing that a different choice of words may lead to something correct. Sure. That's not the point I made, nor what my comment was objecting to.

Comment: I guess I extrapolated a bit on his terminology, and assumed he was talking about a limit.

Answer (score 10):

Since $x_{n+1}-2=\left(x_n-2\right)^2$, we can prove  by induction that $$x_n=(a-2)^{2^n}+2$$ and the rest is smooth.

Answer (score 4):

We can consider the equation: $$a^2 - 4a + 6 = a$$
Which has solutions $a=2$ and $a=3$ (If the sequence were to converge, then it would converge either to $2$ or $3$ , depending on $a$). Additionally, we can check that, for $a>3$:
$$a^2-4a+6 > a >3$$ So for these values, the sequence will not converge. Now, if $a<1$ We can also check that:
$$a^2-4a+6 > 3 \iff  (a-3)(a-1)>0$$
So if $a>1$, then $x_1 >3$ and $x_n$ diverges.
Lastly, for $a \in [1,3]$ if $a \in (2,3)$, then $x_n$ is decreasing, but bounded by $2$, therefore it goes to $2$. If $a \in (1,2) $, then $x_1 \in (2,3)$, and $x_n$ again converges to $2$. Finally, if $a=1,2,3$, then $x_n$ converges to $3,2,3$ respectively because it becomes constant. To summarize:
$$a\in(-\infty,1) \cup (3,+\infty) \iff  x_n  \ \ \ \text{diverges}$$

Comment: Why do we consider the first equation? I tried to understand this as Ive seen it in many exercises but I thought an equation like that could be applied only when we have a relation between x_n x_n-1 and x_n-2 for example

Comment: When we have a convergent sequence, the terms $x_{n+1}$ and ${x_n}$ will become arbitrarily close, we can say they are equal at infinity.

Comment: It is a good tool for guessing the value of a sequence defined by recursion (it does not prove however, its convergence)